# How to render custom css in a deployed streamlit app

Tags: python, html, css, streamlit

I am trying to render custom css in a deployed streamlit app. I have created a custom html table and am displaying it with `components.html()` ([API reference here](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/components/components-api)).

The thing is, I can get this css to render locally when in development by putting my css file in streamlit's `static` folder on my computer and referencing it like so in my custom table html:

```
<link rel=“stylesheet” href=table_style.css” type=“text/css”/>
```

And it works just fine. I have finished my app and deployed it, changing the href to where the css file lives in my streamlit app's repo:

```
<link rel=“stylesheet” href=assets/css/table_style.css” type=“text/css”/>
```

but no css was rendered. I also tried

```
main/assets/css/table_style.css
```

and then tried the full path

```
_user_/_repo_/main/assets/css/table_style.css
```

and using the raw link to the css file itself

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/_user_/_repo_/main/assets/css/table_style.css
```

yet the css doesn't render when deployed with any of these attempts. There has to be a way to get this css referenced when in production...

Comment: Please post your answer as an answer rather than an [edit] to the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[This link has the solution](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/components-html-use-own-css/13284). Basically, you move the css file to the hosted Streamlit's static file, like so:

```py
STREAMLIT_STATIC_PATH = Path(st.__path__[0]) / 'static'
CSS_PATH = (STREAMLIT_STATIC_PATH / "assets/css")
if not CSS_PATH.is_dir():
    CSS_PATH.mkdir()

css_file = CSS_PATH / "table_style.css"
if not css_file.exists():
    shutil.copy("assets/css/table_style.css", css_file)
```

and then the html tag would be:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/table_style.css" type="text/css"/>
```

Since the Streamlit server loads static assets from the static folder of where it is is installed.

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/73600007/3) to the question [How to render custom css in a deployed streamlit app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73600007/how-to-render-custom-css-in-a-deployed-streamlit-app) by the OP [bismo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13132728/bismo) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

if you create a `css.py` file and add some css:

```
css = '''
<style>
.chat-message-box {
    padding: 1.5rem; border-radius: 0.5rem; margin-bottom: 1rem; display: flex
}
'''
```

then in your main streamlit file

```
from your_css_file import css

def main():
    st.write(css,unsafe_allow_html=True)
    ...
```